# Trying to connect a local akka server to another on local network

Tags: c#, akka.net

I’m a bit lost, I’m completly new to akka and I’m struggling a bit.
Long story short, I’m on a work project and the guy who developped the code base is gone so I really don’t know much akka.

I wanna debug my servers locally so I launch a first server called ActorServer (the one having fun with the eventstore) and with this one I don’t have problems

I also have a CommandExecutor server, that is connected to the Actor server, but previously it was set up for remote execution, in the startup i had an Actor Path Anchors looking like this :

```
"akka.tcp://my-sys@host.example.com:5678/user/service-b"
```

And on the documentation I found this :

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/addressing.html#actor-path-anchors

Saying I should have something looking more like this :

```
"akka://my-sys/user/service-a/worker1"
```

But I can’t figure out what I’m supposed to fill it with I tried it :

```
"akka://localhost:60860/system/receptionist"
```

But it didn’t work, I'm getting a

```
System.UriFormatException: 'Can not parse an ActorPath: akka://localhost:60860/system/receptionist'
```

I know that it's because I don't have the "my-sys/user" part right but I don't know what to put there :/

Thanks for reading =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the `ActorPath` format is as follow:

```
<protocol>://<actor-system-name>@<ip>:<port>/<guardian-actor>/<path-to-an-actor>
```

, where:

- **protocol** for remote communication is usually `akka.tcp`
- **actor-system-name** is the name you give to you actor system upon creation via `ActorSystem.Create("actor-system-name", config)`.
- **ip** and **port** are details related to an endpoint on which your remote actor system is listening on. Keep in mind that they are specific and used for comparison.
- **guardian-actor** is a root actor created by ActorSystem itself. Depending on how you've created your actors, it can be one of two options:

  - Guardian for actors created via `actorSystem.ActorOf` is called `user`. This is usually a root of 99% of actors.
  - Guardian for actors created via `actorSystem.SystemActorOf` is called `system`

The rest of the path to an actor relates to an actor hierarchy (in akka, actors are organized in parent-child hierarchies).

Another thing to remember about when setting a remote actor system is to configure it properly - by default actorSystem is local only, and a minimum to work in remote configuration is to use **Akka.Remote** package from NuGet and setup following configuration:

```csharp
// specify hostname and port, your actor system will be listening on
var config = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(@"
    akka.actor.provider = remote
    akka.remote.dot-netty.tcp {
        hostname = ""127.0.0.1""
        port = 3456
    }");

using (var system = ActorSystem.Create("systemName", config))
{

}
```

If your actor system is not configured as `remote` or `cluster` and doesn't have corresponding assemblies, it won't be able to communicate with other actor systems over the network.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer, 
But the thing is that I don't want to launch it remotely, but locally

Comment: What's the problem then? Local-only path equivalent is just `akka` protocol instead of `akka.tcp` and no need for `@ip:port` part as listener doesn't exists from local perspective. Therefore remote path *akka.tcp://my-sys@host.example.com:5678/user/service-b* locally looks like this *akka://my-sys/user/service-b*. If you use selection directly from actor system you should also be able to call it by relative path */user/service-b*.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, I barelly know what I'm doing with this code
I was trying to launch it locally because I used to debug it using Azure Dev Spaces, but it's not working anymore and since I'm not a Kubernetes expert neither, I though it would be a could idea to try debugging it locally
But the project is designed to be launch in Docker containers and I don't know much Docker :| So I tried to run it using Docker Desktop but the Docker build failed ...
So actually I'm trying to make it work again on Kubernetes using Azure Dev Spaces

Comment: And I think I found the problem, but I don't know how to solve it
So, when I'm using our preprod and prod deployments that are pulling images from Azure DevOps everything works fine
But when I'm trying to use Azure Dev Spaces with preprod eventstore it seems that the projects can't communicate outside their namespaces, where the eventstores and the identity server are located
But since we have 2 eventstores (one in prop namespace and the other one in preprod) and 1 identity server (in identity namespace) I think it's a Kubernetes configuration problem rather than a project's one

Comment: Anyway,
thanks for your time and if you know anyone that could help me on this (freelancer included) I'll be glad to get some help

Comment: @AntoineBesnard In case of Kubernetes you must use config like this             
            **port = 8096
            hostname = 0.0.0.0
            public-hostname = (kubernetes service name)**

Answer (score 0):

You must use ActorPath like this:

`akka.tcp://{SysytemName}@localhost:8096/user/{ActorName}`

Where the system name is name which you define in time of system creation:

```
var mySystem = ActorSystem.Create("MySystem", ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(configText));
```

And the ActorName is defined in time of ActorCreation:

```
mySystem.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new MyActor());, "MyActor")
```